# Real Time Javascript Line Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, line, real-time

There is a small function in my application, which needs to present some real-time data to a webpage. I have been trying to research some Javascript examples, like Flot example ”real-time updates”, Highcharts example ”spline updating each second”.  I think they both may fulfil it. But I just started to learn JavaScript. Right now getting stuck and totally no idea about how to accomplish my function. I would much appreciate it if I could get help from you. I have a small budget from my pocket money to support my interests. I am happy to pay the tuition fee for this code.

Basically I can show 100 numerical variables on one page, like 3301, 4390, 3802…. They are refreshed every half second. Now I need to create a line chart which displays these numbers as a series of points connected by line segments. The full functionality of the webpage can
enable real-time data (about 800 points) to be visualized in a dynamic chart by time sequence. In other words, this line chart can show historical data for the predefined period, along with the latest data.

I’ve got 100 variables from one JavaScript file called T1.js. Some part s of the code are as follows:

```
function get_data_loop()
{
...
setTimeout("get_data_loop()",500);
}

...

function process_data(data)
{
var parsed = data.split( "\n" );
var a1 = parseInt(parsed[0],10);
var a2 = parseInt(parsed[1],10);
var a3 = parseInt(parsed[2],10);
var a4 = parseInt(parsed[3],10);
var a5 = parseInt(parsed[4],10);
...
var a97 = (parseInt(parsed[96],10));
var a98 = (parseInt(parsed[97],10));
var a99 = (parseInt(parsed[98],10));
var a100 = (parseInt(parsed[99],10));

document.getElementById("display_a1").value = a1;
document.getElementById("display_a2").value = a2;
document.getElementById("display_a3").value = a3;
...
document.getElementById("display_a98").value = a98;
document.getElementById("display_a99").value = a99;
document.getElementById("display_a100").value = a100;
}
```

And then I just know how to show these numbers on index.html. The code is:

```
<td><input type="text" id="display_a1" value="0" onFocus="blur(this);"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="display_a1" value="0" onFocus="blur(this);"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="display_a3" value="0" onFocus="blur(this);"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="display_a4" value="0" onFocus="blur(this);"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="display_a5" value="0" onFocus="blur(this);"/></td>
...
```

That’s all I have done. Totally mess in my head. No clue how to show these numbers in a line chart.

Is it possible to advise me how I can use any charting component to make it?

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. Is there anybody else can give me more details and code? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [D3 javascript library](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), since there are existing components for making a number of graphs, including line graphs. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/04/01/tutorial-line-chart-in-d3/) from Tulp Interactive that should get you there.